# Searching with a UISearchbar is slow and blocking the main thread

Tags: iphone, uisearchbar

I have a Table with over 3000 entries and searching is very slow.

At the moment I am doing just like in the 'TableSearch' example code (but without scopes)

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText: searchString];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}
```

And the filterContentForSearchText method is as follows:

```
- (void) filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
{
// Update the filtered array based on the search text

// First clear the filtered array.
[filteredListContent removeAllObjects]; 

// Search the main list whose name matches searchText
// add items that match to the filtered array.
if (fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects)
{
    for (id object in fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects)
    {
        NSString* searchTarget = [tableTypeDelegate getStringForSearchFilteringFromObject:object];

        if ([searchTarget rangeOfString:searchText
                options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)].location != NSNotFound)
        {
                [filteredListContent addObject:object];
        }
    }
}
}
```

My question is twofold:

- How do can I make the searching process faster?
- How can I stop the search from blocking the main thread? i.e. stop it preventing the user from typing more characters.

For the second part, I tried "performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:" and "cancelPreviousPerformRequests..." without much success.  I suspect that I will need to use threading instead, but I do not have much experience with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the searching as a NSOperation, so as not to block the main thread.  I also did like  Reinhard suggested and used a `fetchedResultController`.

There is a really good video on NSOperations on the apple developer site.  I was called something like Advanced iPhone part 1 if I recall.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for: "How do can I make the searching process faster?"

It seams that you are using core data results in your table. So it's better let core data do the filtering for you.

So create a new fetchedResultController using a NSPredicate for filtering.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name = %@", searchText];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

using MATCHES instead of =  let you define a regular expression comparison (for a case insensitive compare)